# Update UI from another controller

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I would like to update my `UILabel` on click the button of `ContainerView` contains table `ViewController`. When I try to do this `UILabel's` outlets reference shows nil value exception. I am using Swift3 with Xcode8

Comment: Can you post your code and the line where it's crashing?

Comment: You want to do some changes of uilabel which resides in another view controller.If this is the case, then this issue what you mentioned will occur.Because that view is not in the view hierarchy.To resolve your problem you might use this before accessing your label.
var v = yourViewController.view

Answer (score 2):

Most probably the problem you are seeing is due to the fact that the view that owns this label on another view controller is still not loaded.
This happens often, basically because views owned by a view controller are instantiated in a lazy manner, this means that they are loaded only when required.
To fix that before setting the value on the label, just preload the view by doing something like.

```
_ = another_viewcontroller_instance.view
```

In this way you are forcing the destination view controller to load the view and creating all the necessary connection on the xib.
Even if this fix works, this is not a good way to deal with this kind of pattern (sending info from a VC to another), but since you didn't gave us any further detail this is the only solution I have.